# Can't minimise programs to the desktop in XFce (xUbuntu 9.10)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, desktop, xubuntu, xfce

Using xUbuntu 9.04 I could choose how to use the desktop, 
and I found it really useful to minimise running programs to the desktop. 
Instead of having a trashcan, harddrive, cdrom etc etc and a lot of other tmp files there.

However after upgrading to xUbuntu 9.10 I can't find this great feature, 
do you know how to get it back?

Thanks
Johan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using XFCE on Opensuse, the option is on the "icons" tab of the XFCE desktop settings.

Set "icon type" to "Minimised application icons."

Have a look at the similar settings in Ubuntu, it should be there.